# Evaluate functions data

Tags: php, function

I got:

```
function notification($text, $info = FALSE, $title = FALSE) {
    global $layout_name;
    return '<div class="SmallBox"><div class="MessageContainer"><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="'.($info ? "Valid" : "Error").'Message"><div class="BoxFrameVerticalLeft" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameVerticalRight" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="AttentionSign" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/'.(!$info ? 'attentionsign.gif' : 'valid.png').');" /></div><b>'.(!$title ? (!$info ? 'Wystąpiły następujące błędy:' : 'Sukces!') : $title).'</b><br/>'.$text.'</div><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div></div></div>';
}
```

I wonder if there is a way, to print it out without using `echo notification('text...', FALSE/TRUE, 'some title');`

Just only `notification('text...', FALSE/TRUE, 'some title');` (without `echo`) ?

If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function instead :

```
function notification($text, $info = FALSE, $title = FALSE) {
    global $layout_name;
    echo '<div class="SmallBox"><div class="MessageContainer"><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="'.($info ? "Valid" : "Error").'Message"><div class="BoxFrameVerticalLeft" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameVerticalRight" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="AttentionSign" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/'.(!$info ? 'attentionsign.gif' : 'valid.png').');" /></div><b>'.(!$title ? (!$info ? 'Wystąpiły następujące błędy:' : 'Sukces!') : $title).'</b><br/>'.$text.'</div><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div></div></div>';
}
```

but its still echoing the results, there is no way to avoid using the function `echo`.

**PASSING BY REF**

the function would look something like the function below, but you should change it around to meet your own needs :

```
function notification($text, $info = FALSE, $title = FALSE, &$content) {
    global $layout_name;
    $content .= '<div class="SmallBox"><div class="MessageContainer"><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="'.($info ? "Valid" : "Error").'Message"><div class="BoxFrameVerticalLeft" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameVerticalRight" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="AttentionSign" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/'.(!$info ? 'attentionsign.gif' : 'valid.png').');" /></div><b>'.(!$title ? (!$info ? 'Wystąpiły następujące błędy:' : 'Sukces!') : $title).'</b><br/>'.$text.'</div><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div></div></div>';
}
```

Now if you use this function and pass your `$content` variable, it will change the $content outside the function. note that passing by reference is done in php by adding a `&` before the variable `$VAR` .

Comment: Well I know, but I don't use echo for real - I'm using something like `$content .= notification($text, $info, $title);`

... and then `echo $content;` so instead of writing every time something like `$content .= function()` I would like to use only function() instead. I've heard it can be done using PHP function - `eval()` but have no idea how.

Comment: "there is no way to avoid using the function `echo`" — [`print`](http://www.php.net/print)?

Comment: @icktoofay you are right, but tbh its the same concept, and its not what the OP is looking for!   Isarius,  I think what you are trying to achieve can be done by passing a variable by reference. so you would add another var to the function with your $content, and send the content in with variable and do everything inside the function

Comment: updated my answer, let me know if you dont understand anything

Comment: Aight thanks. What does the `&` before `$content` parameter mean?

Comment: it means that whatever you send into the function as `$content` will be sent by reference, meaning that whatever you do to `$content` it will reflect the variable you sent into the function as `$content`. hope this makes it a bit more clear

Comment: Thank you. Could you be so nice and explain also , why it can not be done using `eval()` function?

Comment: I never claimed it cant be done using `eval()`, its probably possible but it wont be easy and the best solution for your problem. I would suggest avoiding it because it will just make your life harder and the code more complex

Answer (score 0):

The text is returned and the function is PHP, therefore you must either output the result yourself, or modify the function so that it outputs the text itself.

Comment: Thats what I want to reach. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be done using `eval`. But if you say you would otherwise use `$content .= ...` assignments, then modify your function to do so.

```
function notification($text, $info = FALSE, $title = FALSE) {
    global $layout_name;
    global $content;
    $content .= '<div class="SmallBox"><div class="MessageContainer"><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightTop" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="'.($info ? "Valid" : "Error").'Message"><div class="BoxFrameVerticalLeft" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameVerticalRight" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-vertical.gif);" /></div><div class="AttentionSign" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/'.(!$info ? 'attentionsign.gif' : 'valid.png').');" /></div><b>'.(!$title ? (!$info ? 'Wystąpiły następujące błędy:' : 'Sukces!') : $title).'</b><br/>'.$text.'</div><div class="BoxFrameHorizontal" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-horizontal.gif);" /></div>    <div class="BoxFrameEdgeRightBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div><div class="BoxFrameEdgeLeftBottom" style="background-image:url('.$layout_name.'/images/content/box-frame-edge.gif);" /></div></div></div>';
}
```

It's fairly stupid to do so. But for laziness it would work, if all applications share that `$content` output variable in the global scope. (Read: requires `global $content` wherever it was previously defined.)

Comment: I know it's not the best way to do. But I've seen some script like vBulletin or MyBB , and they call error functions by `eval()` function, so I thought I can do that too `:)`.

Comment: You could wrap many things in `eval()`. It's just another name for `include()`. But I wouldn't know how it could be applicable usefully for this task. I'm certain it was used for templating or something different in those bulletin board scripts.